# Cannot move out of borrowed context

Tags: rust

I have a very simple piece of code that I cannot get to compile:

```
struct X;

struct A {
    field: Option<Box<X>>,
}

impl A {
    pub fn get_field(&self) -> Option<&X> {
        return self.field.map(|value| &*value);
    }
}
```

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
 --> src/lib.rs:9:16
  |
9 |         return self.field.map(|value| &*value);
  |                ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content

error[E0597]: `*value` does not live long enough
 --> src/lib.rs:9:40
  |
9 |         return self.field.map(|value| &*value);
  |                                        ^^^^^-
  |                                        |    |
  |                                        |    borrowed value only lives until here
  |                                        borrowed value does not live long enough
  |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 8:5...
 --> src/lib.rs:8:5
  |
8 | /     pub fn get_field(&self) -> Option<&X> {
9 | |         return self.field.map(|value| &*value);
10| |     }
  | |_____^
```

I don't really understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: `self.field.as_ref().map(Box::as_ref);` or `return self.field.as_ref().map(|value| value.as_ref());`

Comment: Thanks @TimDiekmann that's perfect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't really understand why this doesn't work.

Your code defined a struct `A` that may or may not hold a `X` in the heap (not in the stack).

In the method `get_field` you were given a reference to the struct, but you want to get a reference to the inner `X`, if possible.

The above are concluded only by looking at the function signatures and struct definition of `A`.

Looking into the function body, `self.field` is of type `Option<_>`, and `map` is its method. Look at [the documentation for `Option::map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html):

> ```
> pub fn map<U, F>(self, f: F) -> Option<U> 
> where
>   F: FnOnce(T) -> U,
> ```
>
> Maps an `Option<T>` to `Option<U>` by applying a function to a contained value.

It accepts a closure that can only run once, accepts a `Box<X>` in your case, then according to your function return type it should return `&X`. It looks like a perfect match at first glance since if `value: Box<X>` then `*value: X` and `&*value: &X`, but it does not compile! What's wrong?

If you look more carefully at the signature of `map` you see it has 2 parameters, not one. The first parameter is the "method receiver" `self` and its type is `Self`.

In Rust, this means this call will need to consume the method receiver; the object you used to call the method would be no longer valid after this call.

However, your `get_field` method is not allowed to remove the method receiver `self.field`: `self` is only a reference to `A`, so `self.field` is also just a reference . You then cannot call `map` to consume `self.field`.

The solution, is to use `as_ref`:

> ```
> pub fn as_ref(&self) -> Option<&T>
> ```
>
> Converts from `Option<T>` to `Option<&T>`.

Although it says converts from `Option<T>`, but from the signature you can see it accepts `&Option<T>`, so it just moves the outside `&` inside. Now you can use `map`.

```
 pub fn get_field(&self) -> Option<&X> {
    return self.field.as_ref().map(|value| &*value);
 }
```

Now it works.